# Not equals to (!=, <>) in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I want to check a condition that column should not equals to null.I used both(!=, <>) but query gives error. I did not find any not equals to operates in Datastax tutorials. How I can implement not equals to in cqlsh query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Search for Records That Have A Null/Empty Field Using CQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981075/how-can-i-search-for-records-that-have-a-null-empty-field-using-cql)

Answer (score 0):

For direct CQL queries this is probably not a good idea.

If really needed you could use [SASI indices](https://github.com/xedin/sasi).