# how to check all null values in a particular column in cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

by using the below query i am not getting anyrecords

SELECT * FROM test_table where prty_ad_line3_tx = '' and prty_role_type_cd='Co-Borrower' and prty_role_sq_nb =5 limit 10 ALLOW FILTERING;

need help from your end.

Comment: How many records are in your test_table? Are you timing out?

Comment: sample data of 80 records.

Comment: from what I can determine from [reading](http://www.aaronstechcenter.com/null-query-cassandra.php), you can't search by null. Null values aren't allowed in primary keys. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981075/how-can-i-search-for-records-that-have-a-null-empty-field-using-cql)